# smooth scroll to div ID on page Load via URL address

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know how to create a smooth scroll to anchor on page load; with something similar to the below:

```
$(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $('#anchor1').attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

And I have done it 17745005 times `onClick` as navigation to different areas of a vertical website --

> **..But, what I am trying to do now IS, when a URL is accessed let's say** `http://www.cooltimes.com/#scrolltoCOOLplace` <-- **specifically
>   that is typed into the address bar OR clicked on from an external
>   link, then it smooth scrolls to** `#scrolltoCOOLplace` div location
>   within my website.

**Essentially triggering smooth scroll to div element via URL address.**

*Any suggestions on jQuery solutions that allow this kind of functionality?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var param = document.location.pathname;` in your function then pass it to scrollTop.

```
$(function(){
var param = document.location.pathname;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(param.substr(1)).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```